# Need alternative to change function that fires when the page loads

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a piece of styled text below a dropdown using the `change` function, the problem is the option that triggers the change is the first option when the page loads, and because it's disabled (which it needs to be), there is no way to change to it

Instead, I'm wondering if there is an alternative to change that loads the function when the page loads

Just to be clear, the text should not be visible when any other value is selected from the dropdown

I'm also struggling with assigning a class name to the printed text, I have commented out what I thought should work

Days of numerous different code examples, and although I'm closer than a few days ago, I still can't figure out the proper way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Reports</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    select {
      outline: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="reports" class="w3-select w3-border" style="font-size: 20px;" name="reports">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>- Choose -</option>
    <optgroup label="Reports">
      <option value="1">Report 1</option>
      <option value="2">Report 2</option>
      <option value="3">Report 3</option>
      <option value="4">Report 4</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#reports').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
          var x = document.createElement("div");
          // class = "w3-center w3-text-light-green"
          x.textContent = "Choose Report From Menu";
          document.body.appendChild(x);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The desired result is have the "styled" text appear when the page loads, but disappear when any other option from the dropdown is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `onchange="hide()"` to `<select...>` and add div with text in body and after change just hide it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reports</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            select {
                outline: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="reports" class="w3-select w3-border" style="font-size: 20px;" name="reports" onchange="hide()">
            <option value="0" disabled selected>- Choose -</option>
            <optgroup label="Reports">
                <option value="1">Report 1</option>
                <option value="2">Report 2</option>
                <option value="3">Report 3</option>
                <option value="4">Report 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        
        <div id="msg">"Choose Report From Menu"</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hide() {
                msg.style.display='none';
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to execute that function one time when the page loads, try something like this:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            function reportsChange() {
                if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                    var x = document.createElement("div");
                    // class = "w3-center w3-text-light-green"
                    x.textContent = "Choose Report From Menu";
                    document.body.appendChild(x);
                }
            }
            $('#reports').change(function () {
                reportsChange();
            });
            reportsChange();
        });
```

This will execute the "reportsChange" function once when loading the page, and it will also be available for you to use whenever the on change event triggers.